Databricks JDBC Insert into Array field
I am trying to insert some data into a databricks table which has Array fields (field1 & field2). I am using JDBC for the connection and my POJO class looks like this
public class A{
    private Long id;
    private String[] field1;
    private String[] field2;
}

I am using
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(String sql, final List<Object[]> batchArgs, final int[] argTypes)

where I have a list of Objects for class A.
the argtype code for the fields, field1 & field2 are 2003 since I am using the java.sql.Type.Arrray for these fields.
While executing, I am getting the following error
[Databricks][JDBC](11500) Given type does not match given object: [Ljava.lang.String;@3e1346b0.

Should I be using some other code for these fields?
How do I insert data into a Array field using JDBCTemplate
This is how my insert code looks
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sqlQuery,parametersforBatchInsert.getParameterListForBatch(),parametersforBatchInsert.getDataTypeArray());


public ParameterizedDTO getPreparedStatmentParametersForBatch(List<T> parameterSourceList) throws Exception{
    ParameterizedDTO dto = new ParameterizedDTO();
    Field[] fields = class_name.getDeclaredFields();
    Object[] parameterArray = null;
    int[] dataTypeArray = new int[fields.length];
    List<Object[]> parameterList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i< parameterSourceList.size();i++){
        parameterArray = new Object[fields.length];
        Object parameterObject = parameterSourceList.get(i);
        for(int j=0;j< fields.length;j++){
            fields[j].setAccessible(true);
            parameterArray[j] = fields[j].get(parameterObject);
            if(dto.getDataTypeArray() == null) {
                dataTypeArray[j] = getFieldType(fields[j].getType().getName());
            }
        }
        parameterList.add(parameterArray);
        if(dto.getDataTypeArray() == null) {
            dto.setDataTypeArray(dataTypeArray);
        }
    }
    dto.setParameterListForBatch(parameterList);

    return dto;
}


public Integer getFieldType(String fieldType){
    return switch (fieldType.toUpperCase()) {
        case BOOLEAN, LANG_BOOLEAN -> Types.BOOLEAN;
        case STRING -> Types.VARCHAR;
        case INT, INTEGER -> Types.INTEGER;
        case TIMESTAMP -> Types.TIMESTAMP;
        case LONG -> Types.BIGINT;
        case SQL_DATE -> Types.DATE;
        case STRING_ARRAY -> Types.ARRAY;
        default -> 0;
    };

}

and this is my insert command
Insert into catalog.schema.A values(?,?,?)

You need to show the code you are using to attempt insert.

Hey @SamuelMarchant added the insert command
